# How to embed HTML or XML in reStructuredText (sphinx) so the browser cna render them?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I just need to embed a small piece of html or xml in the reStructuredText (sphinx) so that the browser can render them in the generated HTML files, like the following little piece

```
.. raw:: html
  <a href="testurl">testurl</a>
```

or

```
.. raw:: html
  <math><apply><plus/><ci>a</ci><apply><minus/><ci>b</ci><ci>c</ci></apply></apply></math>
```

No matter I tried directives like "literal", "raw", "container", "code", either the html code is displayed as the **inner text** of some "p" block (so the browser display the code rather than render it), or the code just **disappear** from the output.

**What is the correct way to embed html or xml in the reStructuredText (sphinx) so the browser can render them**? I just want to html or xml just be placed there intact.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add a blank line between the [`raw`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) directive and your code.

```
.. raw:: html

    <a href="testurl">testurl</a>
```

I would suggest indenting 4 spaces to be consistent with Python formatting, but 2 is fine.

Comment: Signpost to [a toctree derived from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61502938).