# Can I add a horizontal bar to a table of contents in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, horizontal-line, toctree

I'm developing documentation in Sphinx, and would like to separate sections in my table of contents using horizontal bars.

I often see this in menus:

[image]

Is there a way to do it in sphinx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python sphinx [`.. toctree::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree) directive doesn't allow much variation besides the documents you include in the directive body, plus a few directive options.

What I've seen others do in this case is splitting one `toctree` into several, including reStructuredText in between them.

You could use an alternative to the `toctree`. Quoting the documentation:

> Note
>
> For local tables of contents, use the standard reST [contents directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents).

The easiest way is splitting the menu into several `toctree`s including a HTML horizontal ruler between them:

```
Sphinx_test
===========


.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4
   
   undo
   redo

.. raw:: html

   <hr>

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4
   
   cut
   copy

.. raw:: html

   <hr>
   
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4
      
   find
   Speech
```

And the result:

[image]